# How can I get devices name after gathering all the IP addresses connected in a network? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dns, ip, ip-address, hostname

I am using lan_scanner flutter package to gather IP Addresses of a network.I want to also get the hostname of each particular address. Any ideas on how can I achieve that?

I tried using some other packages but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

you can connect to that device and ask for it's hostname

first add a server socket to listen for clients (devices)

```
const int port  = 7575;
try {
  ServerSocket server = await ServerSocket.bind(deviceIp, port);
  server.listen((client) {
    client.listen((data) {
      final ip = client.remoteAddress.address;
      final hostname = String.fromCharCodes(data);
      print("hostname of $ip is $hostname");
    });
  });
} on SocketException catch(_) {
  print('failed to create a server socket');
}
```

then for each device connect to the server and send the device hostname

```
try {
  Socket client = await Socket.connect(targetIp, port);
  client.write(Platform.localHostname);
  client.destroy();
} on SocketException catch(_) {
  print('failed to connect to the server');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't manage to make it work this way.